# Create and Update record from same field with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm building a rails app that will be used by people to log how many steps they took on a given week.

The functionality of the application includes an activity logger that a person can enter steps into, click a week shown on a calendar, and click submit. The application will then create a record of the person's id, when the steps were taken, and how many steps. The same step logger should update the step count if the same user logs a different number of steps on a day.

**I'm having trouble getting the logic into the controller to check if a step record exists that has the same user_id and step_date as the step being added.**

I've looked into "`find_or_initialize_by`"/"`find_or_create_by`" but haven't had much luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Code below.

Logging form (**_activityLog.html.erb**):

```
<%= simple_form_for Step.new do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :challenge_id, :value => "1" %>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">Steps I've Taken:</span>
        <%= f.input :step_count, label: false, id: "step_count", class: "form-control", required: true %>
      </div>
      <div id="weekpicker"></div>
      <%= f.input :step_date, as: :hidden, input_html: { class: 'week' } %>
      <%= f.button :submit, "Log Activity", class: "submit btn-block", id: "submitWeekly" %>
<% end %>
```

Steps Controller (**steps_controller.rb**)

```
class StepsController < ApplicationController


before_action :set_step, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /steps
  # GET /steps.json
  def index
    @steps = Step.all
  end
  # GET /steps/1
  # GET /steps/1.json
  def show
    redirect_to(:back)
  end
  # GET /steps/new
  def new
    @step = Step.new
  end
  # GET /steps/1/edit
  def edit
  end
  # POST /steps
  # POST /steps.json
  def create
    @step = Step.new(step_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @step.save
        format.html { redirect_to @step, notice: 'Step was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @step }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @step.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # PATCH/PUT /steps/1
  # PATCH/PUT /steps/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @step.update(step_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @step, notice: 'Step was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @step }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @step.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /steps/1
  # DELETE /steps/1.json
  def destroy
    @step.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to steps_url, notice: 'Step was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_step
      @step = Step.find(params[:id])
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def step_params
      params.require(:step).permit(:user_id, :challenge_id, :step_date, :step_count)
    end
end
```

Step Model (**step.rb**)

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :challenge
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
def create
  # ... leaving some stuff out :) 
  @step = Step.where(user_id: params[:user_id], step_date: params[:step_date]).first_or_initialize(step_params) # or first_or_create 
  # ... other code here (leaving more stuff out)  
end
```

Comment: Thank you ! This was perfect. For reference my final code: 

`@step = Step.where(user_id: step_params[:user_id], step_date: step_params[:step_date]).first_or_initialize(step_params)`

`@step.update(step_count: step_params[:step_count])`